# Infinite scroll new element

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to add a voting function to each new element within the Infinite Scroll. I managed to get the voting functions working but this doesn't work with new elements loaded when scrolling down the page.

Pastebin URL: http://pastebin.com/0eNYDXrm

I've attached my code below. Any help or advice would be appreciated...Many Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.protected-post-form').center();
$('#content').infinitescroll({
    debug: false,
    loading: {},
    state: {
        currPage: "1"
    },
    nextSelector: "div.navigation a:first",
    navSelector: "div.navigation",
    contentSelector: "#content",
    itemSelector: "#content  div.post",
    pathParse: ["<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST "] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI "] ?>page/", "/"]
}, function() {
    window.setTimeout(infinite_scroll_callback(), 1);
});


function applyvote(elements) {
    $(elements).each(
    $(".vote a").click(

    function() {
        var some = jQuery(this);
        var thepost = jQuery(this).attr("post");
        var theuser = jQuery(this).attr("user");
        jQuery.post("<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/vote.php", {
            user: theuser,
            post: thepost
        }, function(data) {
            var votebox = ".vote" + thepost + " span";
            jQuery(votebox).text(data);
        });
    });
    });
}

$(elem).infinitescroll(options, applyvote(arrayOfNewElems));

});    


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(elem).infinitescroll(options, applyvote(arrayOfNewElems));
```

The second argument to `.infinitescroll` is a callback function. `applyvote(arrayOfNewElems)` is a not a function but a function call (so it evaluates to whatever is returned by your calling the function, which seems to be `undefined`). Use this instead:

```
$(elem).infinitescroll(options, applyvote);
```

Now you're passing a function which inifinitescroll itself will call when new content is loaded, and it will pass the new elements created.

Comment: It's very important to know the difference between the two. What's the next problem? Debugger saying anything?